# symfony forward with DI

Tags: php, symfony

I have a DI problem in symfony2 controller

```
public function __construct(EngineInterface $engine,EntityManager $entityManager,...
```

config

```
acme.acme_controller:
    class: %acme.acme_controller_class%
    arguments:
        - @templating
        - @doctrine.orm.entity_manager
        ...
    calls:
        - [ setContainer, [ @service_container ] ]
```

basicly this works if I display a page in browser, but it breaks if I try to use

```
$this->forward("Acme:Acme:something", array('id' => $id));
```

All I get is

```
Argument 1 passed to ::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface, none given, called in app\cache\dev\classes.php on line 1543 and defined
```

Redirects works fine so what am I doing wrong here? Symfony 2.3.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the service id (as opposed the the bundle class name) to get DI to kick in.  Something like:

```
$this->forward("acme.acme_controller:somethingAction", array('id' => $id));
```

Edited to add Action per the comment.

Comment: thanks, as I'm trying it now, it requires :somethingAction as just :something ends with
    500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException